# how to get dump db2 database?

Tags: db2, mysql, dump, lookup-tables

I have 3 questions :
1. How to get db2 dump database -with command like mysqldump-
2. If I want this dump to contain lookup tables is this possible to do that or I have to export lookup tables manually one by one ?
3. How I can use the output dump file after that ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers to your questions:

1. A Mysql dump is called a backup in DB2. It creates a binary file that you can restore in the same kind of platform (Window, Linux). It contains the tables definition (DDL), the data and the security.
2. and 3. There is another command that just extract the DDL of the defined objects. The tool is called db2look. When using a backup / restore method, you do not need db2look (DDL).
   You can also extract the data from DB2 with export command. There is a tool that ease the process called db2move that can perform the export, and also the import or load.

When performing a migration, it is a common practice to use the combination db2look + db2move in order to recreate the database, for example in another platform.

Documentation about the different commands.

- Backup command - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001933.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-4-8&lang=en
- Restore command - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001976.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-4-109&lang=en
- db2move command - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-6-84&lang=en
- db2look command - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-6-82&lang=en

Comment: so I can use db2look ---- > for dump database  and db2move for backup ,   can you tell me the command of db2look

Comment: I modified the question with references to the commands. Please take a look to the commands.